# Why project can't find Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs 3.0.0.0

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Functions (v2) project in Visual Studio 15.8.6, which has Azure Functions and Web Job Tools 5.2.60618.0 installed.  I'm using a ServiceBusTrigger. When I try to compile the project, I keeping getting:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>      at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
>      at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
>      at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
>      at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
>      at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeParameterInfo parameter, RuntimeType caType)
>      at System.Attribute.InternalParamGetCustomAttributes(ParameterInfo param, Type type, Boolean inherit)
>      at MakeFunctionJson.ParameterInfoExtensions.GetDisabledAttribute(ParameterInfo parameterInfo)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at MakeFunctionJson.MethodInfoExtensions.GetDisabled(MethodInfo method)
>      at MakeFunctionJson.MethodInfoExtensions.HasUnsuportedAttributes(MethodInfo method, String& error)
>      at MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.<GenerateFunctions>d__9.MoveNext()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.TryGenerateFunctionJsons()
>      at MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.TryRun()
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> Error generating functions metadata
>     InSysFunctionDeviceMinuteDataProcessorV2    C:\Users\Dr Kurt
>   Richardson.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.22\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets  39

Although it is complaining that Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs 3.0.0.0 is missing, it is clearly listed in the installed packages:

[image]

One thing I have noticed is that, although the project is using .NET Standard v2.0.3 the error message refers to a path containing **netstandard1.0** (...nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\1.0.22\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets 3) .  Nuget says that v1.0.22 of Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions targets **.NETStandard, Version=v2.0**.  Furthermore Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs is located in a **netstandard2.0** folder.  Could this be the problem? Or something else?

Comment: I actually had 15.9.02009.0 of Azure Functions and Web Job Tools installed - nit sure where I pulled 5.2.60618.0 from. D'oh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [package references in v2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Updating-your-function-app-extensions#what-nuget-packages-do-i-need).

`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus` has been **renamed** to `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus` and `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs` is included in `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions`, no need to install it separately.

Please update Azure Functions and Web Job Tools to [latest version](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/blob/master/VS-AzureTools-ReleaseNotes.md#release-notes)(right now is 15.10.2009.0).

With latest extension and template, when we create a service bus trigger, the default nuget dependencies right now are

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus v3.0.0
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions v1.0.22
```

Comment: Perfect - many thanks indeed.  It was the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus reference that was the problem.  Not sure where I pulled v5.2.60618.0 from - I actually have 15.9.02009.0, but will update as you suggest.  Many thanks for responding so quickly - this has been troubling me for days.  Where could I have learnt about the change from Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus to Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus?

Comment: @ProfNimrod Sorry about the miss, have added the official link.

Comment: Went through this exact same thing. It’s posted on the release notes for the GA of Azure Functions v2 and made reference to in a couple of issues. Basically, if you’re using v2, best to be scouring every drop of content off those issues and release notes. There are lots of little gotchas like this.

Comment: @Jeff Good point. For VS development, updating `Azure Functions and Web Job Tools` basically is enough for new functions, while updating sdk references along with [host.json change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#sample-hostjson-file) should make old v2 functions work.

Answer (score 0):

Update **Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions** to its latest version